# How to get a few result from object in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Example:

```
specialization(saw, wood).
specialization(plane, wood).

spec_Q(X):-
specialization(S,X),
//do something with S
.
```

But `S` return only 1 result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for `findall/3`.

```
specialization(saw, wood).
specialization(plane, wood).

spec_Q(X) :-
    findall(S, specialization(S,X), SL),
    print(SL).
```

You can test it:

```
?- spec_Q(wood).
[saw,plane]
true.
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a foreach(or something like this) in Prolog?

Comment: Prolog uses [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) naturally. For this reason the `findall` is often unnecessary. And perhaps your program could be written without `findall` too.